# Yahoo Weather API: Get data from another day

Tags: php, api, yahoo, weather

Is it possible to get the weather data for a city for the next seven days?
I only found the solution to get temperatures for today...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Yahoo API supports extended forecasts. Take a look at the [Weather Underground API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/), they have a 10 day forecast available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what solution you talk about but Yahoo Weather provides  the current conditions, rest of the day forecast and next 9 days forecast in the same answer you get when doing a yql request. For example:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D4118%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

...will return the conditions and 10-day forecast (including the remains of current day) for Toronto, ON, in metric units, XML-formatted. Copy and paste this line in the address box of any browser and look for the yweather:forecast tag in the answer.